# Qt Creator won't open CMake C++ Project in OSX

Tags: qt, cmake, qt-creator

I'm trying to work on an [open-source project](https://github.com/cr8tr/omnidome) in Qt Creator on OSX. When I open the CMakeLists.txt like other CMake projects in Qt Creator it doesn't open the project. No folders, source files, not even the CMakeList.txt shows up in Qt Creator, just a completely blank project.

[image: Empty Qt Creator Window doesn't even show CMakeLists.txt.]

What could cause a project to do this?

Edit: the project opens properly in Ubuntu. It shows the CMakeLists.txt, source files, and everything. It even builds properly when I CMake in the command line on OSX. Qt Creator in OSX just does not open this project properly.

Eit 2: My build settings are completely empty too. There are no General Messages or messages of any kind.

[image]

Comment: Did you get an error during generation? CMake does create empty solutions/IDE projects when something goes wrong during (re-)building the project. Check again from command line, I suspect some syntax problem in your `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: When I run CMake in Creator nothing happens. When I run CMake in the command line the project builds with a few minor errors that don't even stop the build.

Comment: What version of Qt Creator are you using? Can you confirm in Qt Creator's settings whether it is using the cmake executable you expect it to (look in the _Build & Run_ section)? Also show the _General Messages_ output pane (click the up-down icon in the status bar at the bottom of the window to get a context menu allow you to show it) and check for any helpful messages there.

Comment: See Edit 2, Nothing in build settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your Preferences (Cmd+, on Mac) and go to the *Build & Run* and then *CMake* tab, do you see any CMake version listed there? For me, I have to add a manual entry because it doesn't automatically find my CMake. My manual entry is set to `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake` so compare that with what you have in your settings. 
[image: Build & Run -> CMake tab showing the CMake path manually set to /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake]
Then restart Qt Creator and reopen your project. Go to *Build & Run* again and make sure the *Kit* you have selected for your project has a *CMake Tool* set (should be automatic if you have just the one CMake entry listed on the CMake tab).
[image: Build & Run -> Kits showing CMake and the CMake generator have been found.]

**Background Information**

It looks like you are using Qt Creator 4.0. With that version, they changed a number of things related to how CMake projects are handled. When you first open a project, it won't create the build directory if it doesn't exist. Instead, it will run CMake in a temporary directory. This would be shown in the *General Messages* output pane if you had it open. Once you manually create the output directory as it appears in your project's *Build Settings*, Qt Creator will switch to running CMake in there instead. There's no indication this is happening apart from what is logged in the *General Messages* output pane, even if there's a problem with your CMakeLists.txt.

In your case, if there's genuinely nothing appearing in your *General Messages* output pane and CMake is working fine from the command line, that suggests something may be wrong with your Qt Creator settings.

Comment: I had to manually set cmake, as you did. However I still receive no messages in the General tab. When I hover over my `Desktop Qt 5.6.0 clang 64bit` Kit I receive the warning `CMake Tool is unconfigured. CMake generator will be ignored.`

Comment: Let's discuss this on chat (invite should have been sent)

Comment: Thanks we got it. After deleting `CMakeCache.txt`, the `CMakeFiles` folder and `Omnidome.cbp`, Qt Creator with CMake I can now use debug.

Comment: I had the same problem, but it was because I only selected the `Unix Makefiles` generator. You actually have to select `CodeBlocks` as the second generator for Qt Creator to be able to find the files. I did that, and my files appeared magically in the Projects view.

Comment: I had same problem caused by MacOS error 43 (filesystem bug when files can't be moved to the trash). I had to Force quit Finder from the system menu, delete the build folder and restart Qt Creator in order to fix it.